# Using of multiple localBusiness in one page - schema. is it correct?

Tags: html, css, schema

using of multiple localBusiness in one page - schema. is it correct?

Here is my code.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <span itemprop="description"> A superb collection of fine gifts and clothing
  to accent your stay in Mexico Beach.</span>
  <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">3102 Highway 98</span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Mexico Beach</span>,
    <span itemprop="addressRegion">FL</span>
  </div>
  Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">850-648-4200</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <h1><span itemprop="name">Beachwalk Beachwear & Giftware</span></h1>
</div>
```

Please guide me if I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use multiple **localBusiness** in one page just make sure there are no error in the **markup**, see the http://schema.org/LocalBusiness and test you code in [google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/)

for example in you code there are `2 error` and `one warning` in the first **localBusiness** there is no **image** and no **name** and those are required
and The **priceRange** field is recommended.
in the second **localBusiness** there are 1 error and 3 warning.
like i said text your code and then put it in your web site.
if the  google Structured Data Testing Tool say that everything is okey then there is no problem